# building with gyp failed

Tags: 14.04, server

I am trying to build the  framework in this git repository. 
https://github.com/cksystemsgroup/scal

I don't have root privileges on the server I am building this on, so I am doing this as a normal user on my private directory.

to my knowledge the dependencies for this are already installed and so I only need to build. The instructions to do that are s follows:

```
tools/make_deps.sh
build/gyp/gyp --depth=. scal.gyp
V=1 BUILDTYPE=Debug make
V=1 BUILDTYPE=Release make
```

I cloned the git repository and this is how it is looking:

```
:~/ictp/scal$ ls
AUTHORS     common.gypi   glue.gyp     paper.pdf  src
autogen.sh  configure.ac  LICENSE      README.md  tools
build       data          Makefile.am  scal.gyp   upstream.gyp
```

this is the output I have on my terminal when I tried the commands they mention:

```
~/ictp/scal$ tools/make_deps.sh
 -> updating dependencies for scal

 -> gyp... 

Already up to date.

 -> gyp... done



:~/ictp/scal$ build/gyp/gyp --depth=. scal.gyp
-bash: build/gyp/gyp: No such file or directory

:~/ictp/scal$ BUILDTYPE=Release make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I have tried to delete build/gyp and update the directory using :  `tools/make_deps.sh`
when I follow that with : `build/gyp/gyp --depth=. scal.gyp`

I get the following error:

```
fatal: remote error: 


Invalid authentication credentials.

Please generate a new identifier:
  https://chromium.googlesource.com/new-password
```

what does this mean?

Comment: So what does `ls build/gyp/` say? since it's populated by a git clone (from `tools/make_deps.sh`) perhaps try just deleting the `build` dir and running `tools/make_deps.sh` again

Comment: the directory  build/gyp/ is empty actually. I will try to delete it, update and report back.

Comment: I got the build/gyp back with **tools/make_deps.sh ** but it's again empty.

Comment: Hmm... it works for me (on a 18.04 box, with no git credentials) - I suspect it's something wrong with your git config, or possibly a proxy or networking issue

Comment: @steeldriver I have this strange credentiels error, I just cloned the repository (which is a public) to my private directory on the server (I added this part in the question). I don't understand why ?

Comment: Sorry - I don't know anything about how git authentication works - I suspect you have some kind of cached credentials that it is trying to use (even though the repo is public and doesn't appear to require any). Maybe start by running `git config --list` in the `build/gyp` directory to see what it shows?